# Angular JS: ng-repeat does not render within table tag

Tags: angularjs

The following code snippet displays only the `thead` in my page:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="table-heading">
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Played</th>
            <th>Won</th>
            <th>Drawn</th>
            <th>Lost</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div ng-repeat="(tableKey, tableRow) in tableObject.table">
            <tr id="table-body">
                <td>{{tableKey}}</td>
                <td>{{tableRow.gamesPlayed}}</td>
                <td>{{tableRow.gamesWon}}</td>
                <td>{{tableRow.gamesDrawn}}</td>
                <td>{{tableRow.gamesLost}}</td>
                <td>{{tableRow.gamesPoints}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, if I am to comment out the `table` tag, and the `thead` element, and leave the `tbody` in, the table-body displays fine.

What concept around tables am I missing here?

Comment: Is that valid HTML, maybe run it through the validator, I suspect that DIV in the tbody is invalid. You can put the ng-repeat directly on the tr if you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right, moving the ng-repeat to the tr resolved this, see the answer below

Comment: I belive this wont render since this is broken html, under tbody you should have imidiatly a table tag tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="table-heading">
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Played</th>
            <th>Won</th>
            <th>Drawn</th>
            <th>Lost</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(tableKey, tableRow) in tableObject.table">
            <td>{{tableKey}}</td>
            <td>{{tableRow.gamesPlayed}}</td>
            <td>{{tableRow.gamesWon}}</td>
            <td>{{tableRow.gamesDrawn}}</td>
            <td>{{tableRow.gamesLost}}</td>
            <td>{{tableRow.gamesPoints}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`id="table-body"` also removed because we cannot have same ids on page.

Comment: What do you mean by the same ids on page?

Comment: "The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id."

Answer (score 2):

No need of `div` here and if you want to set id for each row, you can use [`ngAttr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) directive

so your `<tbody>` will be,

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-attr-id = "{{ 'tablebodyObj_' + tableRow.index }}" 
        ng-repeat = "(tableKey, tableRow) in tableObject.table">
        <td>{{tableKey}}</td>
        <td>{{tableRow.gamesPlayed}}</td>
        <td>{{tableRow.gamesWon}}</td>
        <td>{{tableRow.gamesDrawn}}</td>
        <td>{{tableRow.gamesLost}}</td>
        <td>{{tableRow.gamesPoints}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```